# C++:can the condition state of cin stream be recovered after entering EOF

Tags: c++

Here is my code for test:

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
istream& func(istream &);
int main()
{
   if(func(cin))
       cout<<"good"<<endl;
   return 0;
}
istream& func(istream &is)
{
    int num;
    is.clear();
    auto old_state = is.rdstate();
    while(is>>num)
        cout<<num<<endl;
    is.setstate(old_state);
    return is;
}
```

The problem is:if I enter a char or the mark of EOF(ctr_z in my system) to break the while loop,then the program terminates directly.I was expecting that the cin stream can be reset to a normal state and be returned:

```
if(func(cin))
       cout<<"good"<<endl;
```

But I can't get that output when program ends.
So what's wrong with my understanding?

Answer (score 1):

You need to ignore the eror and then clear it. So as an example you just need to change your while loop to something like this:

```
    while(true)
    {
        if(is>>num)
            cout<<num<<endl; //if cin is numeric
        else // we have an error
        {
            is.ignore(); // ignore the last error (else your program will run crazy)
            is.clear(); // clear the state
            break; // terminate console reading
        }
    }
```

Comment: Your idea is good.But" the console is likely to be disconnected after an end of stream indicator (e.g., Ctrl-D or Ctrl-Z)." ,like Dietmar Kühl pointed out. Entering "EOF",program ends.It is possibly system-related.

Comment: Oh, I totally ignored the EOF-part of the question. So wouldn't a portable way be to use signal handlers like 'signal(SIGINT, mysignalhandlingfunction);
' and there to 'clear()' the state of 'cin'?

Answer (score 0):

It's because [`setstate`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/setstate) does not really *clear* the old flags (read the linked reference to see why)

If you want to completely reset the flags then you need to use the [`clear`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/clear) function. Not that I really recommend it though, as it gives you a false state of the stream. Instead you should explicitly check the state.

Answer (score 0):

The state can be recovered after an invalid input: failure to parse the input according to the expected type just sets `std:: ios_base::failbit` which can be `clear()`ed. Since the character causing the problem is not removed, you'll probably need to get rid of it (e.g. using `ignore()`) or parae the data differently.

Although EOF is also just a flag  (`std::ios_base::eofbit`) clearing it in general won't recover the from having reached the end of the stream. Specific streams may have a way to carry on reading but the console is likely to be disconnected after an end of stream indicator (e.g., Ctrl-D or Ctrl-Z). Depending on the system it may be possible to create a new connection to the console, e.g., by opening a file stream to `/dev/tty`.

If you really want to use control characters to indicate special processing you'll need to disable the default processing and manage them within the program. On UNIX systems you'd set the stream into noncanonical mode using `tcgetattr()` and `tcsetattr()`. Once this is done all characters entered are seen and can be processed accoringly, probably in a custom stream buffer. I don't know how to do something similar on other systems.